# Verify previous record BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can check the previous record in BigQuery?

I have this table that contains the list of all products a client bought, ordered by date.

[image: database example]

I need to create an additional column that will return "1" when the previous record was product "B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `LAG()` to move the previous row to the next one, in this case
  we are doing this to get previous product
- if previous product is same as of current product then we create a a column called `falg` and put 1 in it

```
with previous_product as (
select *,lag(product) over(partition by person_id order by date) as previous_product
from [table name]
)
select
case when product = previous_product then 1 else 0 end as flag
from previous_product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`.  I would leave the flag as true/false and use:

```
select t.*,
       ('B' = lag(product, 1, 'A') over (partition by person_id order by date)) as flag
from t;
```